# Packaging wxpython app with py2app changes GUI behavior

Tags: python, macos, wxpython, py2app

I'm getting some really strange behavior with a wxpython app I'm working on. When I run the application directly (e.g. python ./main.py), everything works fine. However, when I run the packaged version of the app (made with py2app), I get some odd behavior.

Specifically: I have a checkbox that, when checked, opens a wx.Frame. When running the application directly it works fine. When I'm using the packaged version, nothing happens on the first click of the checkbox. To get the window to show up, I have to uncheck the checkbox and then re-check it. The click event *does* get fired off, and frame.show() gets called, but the window never shows up on the first click.

Here's the py2app config code:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['MessengerVisualization.py']
DATA_FILES = ['UVVSSCIC.FMT', 'data', 'magfield', 'shaders', 'textures', 'features.csv', 'libspice.dylib', 'Na.M2.PSD.fast.stick.density.dat', 'messenger_kernels']
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': False}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app']
)
```

Here's an abbreviated version of the code that show()s the window:

```
def handler(evt):
    if cb.GetValue():
        frame = UVVSFrame(None, -1, 'MASCS UVVS Data: %s (%s)' % (species,typestr),
                  size=(854, 480), controller=self, view=view_b,
                  data_provider=self.uvvs_provider,
                  shader_style=style)
        frame.identifier = wx.NewId()
        frame.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, frame_cleanup(frame.identifier))
        frame.Show()
```

It looks like other people have had problems with argv_emulation, but setting it to False didn't seem to fix my problems.

I also tried doing frame.show(), frame.hide(), frame.show() when catching the event (in case something was preventing the first show()), but that didn't help.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you sure its getting called?

Comment: I have observed the same issue, it seems like in the py2app version the windows do get created but for some reason they are not visible. For me the issue only exists with newer wxpython versions (2.9.2.4) while older versions (2.8.10.1) do not have that problem. Do you also have the issue with older versions?

Comment: I'm not sure what causes it, but it has been around for a long time.  In the code generated by Boa Constructor they used to (and probably still do) generate a line like "frame.Show(); frame.Hide(); frame.Show()" for the main frame of the application.  IIRC it had something to do with how Boa was executing the script and something in the system settings or shortcut properties or something weird like that, and that it didn't have the same problems when run outside of Boa.

Comment: I had no luck with frame.Hide() and frame.Show(), but I discovered that after showing a modal dialog all the windows suddenly behave normally.

Comment: Anyone have a solution to this, as I have to same problem?

Answer (score 1):

I do not have a solution, but I want to add my observations (not sure why I can't comment on the question).

I'm facing the same problem with a button handler creating a wx.Dialog.  The dialog only appears after I click the window again.  However, wx.MessageDialog's appear properly using ShowModal.  Any other ideas?  Is this issue common to all app builders, or just py2app?